# Deducting moving expenses - what about item replaced after being broken in move

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, irs, deduction

During a qualified move that coincided with a job change (an IRS requirement for this particular deduction), an item that was shipped arrived at the new location broken, a replacement was bought.

What parts of this are deductible?

The shipping costs were deductible, but what about the costs of replacement? This is unclear to me.

The item itself is not a requirement for work, and is solely a possession that originally incurred shipping costs from the old home to the new home.

Comment: Would you (or the removal company) not have had insurance which covered this?

Comment: @Vicky there was insurance, no claim was submitted as the value of items claimed when signing up for the insurance was low for a lower insurance rate. Coupled with online reviews suggesting not to bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have met the requirements for a mover's deduction as stated in [Topic 455](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc455.html) there is nothing mentioned about reimbursements of lost or damaged property in the move. Furthermore, checking [Form 3903](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f3903.pdf) there is nothing about the matter either. 
My recommendation is to look at [Publication 547](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p547.pdf), specifically:

> Types of Reimbursements

The publication discusses loss and theft, but also casualties of property as noted in [Form 4684](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4684.pdf). The caveat is it must be through an insurance provider.

---

> @Vicky there was insurance, no claim was submitted as the value of items claimed when signing up for the insurance was low for a lower insurance rate. Coupled with online reviews suggesting not to bother.

This may cause you issues in the future if it was a substantial item.

But to answer your question: 
**Without a claim, proof of insurance, or any like matter, you will be out-of-luck proving this case to the IRS.**